# Do I need a browser plugin to play Battlefield 4, or is there a stand-alone client?

Tags: pc, battlefield-4

I really don't want to install a browser plugin to play a multiplayer game. I downloaded my game through Origins. Do I really need a browser plugin to play online?

Comment: Why don't you want to use a browser plug-in?  Are you asking for a stand-alone app?

Comment: I guess when I originally downloaded it I figured it would be like any other game - a standalone application. I just find it inconvenient and annoying that I have to go through my browser to play the game and didn't know if there was a workaround for this.

Comment: you can you Battlelog app on your smartphone instead of web browser I believe. I never tried it, so I'm not 100% sure about it. But the server browser doesn't exist in the game itself, so you should use web browser or a smartphone app

Comment: In the end, this is a much better solution for game browsing than using the game itself.  They can patch bugs/add features to the browser much easier than patching the game across 5 ecosystems (PC, XB1, 360, PS3/4).  Throughout the life of BF3, the game browser gained feature after feature.  I expect the same for the BF4 browser.

Comment: A few months later, I don't really find it annoying anymore - it's just different. It's kind of a pain for single monitors but for dual monitors it's fantastic.

Comment: http://www.rockpapershotgun.com/2013/11/13/so-i-thought-id-play-battlefield-4s-single-player-about-that/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you really need to install the browser plugin.

The simple and quick way to get in is to right click on the origin icon in your systray and launch BF4. It will take you right in to the browser automagically.

Comment: That's BS, so glad I didn't have to pay for it (free from AMD APU). They are almost definitely tracking and or spying on you with their plugin.

Comment: http://www.rockpapershotgun.com/2013/11/13/so-i-thought-id-play-battlefield-4s-single-player-about-that/